# Touch pad not working at all on 23.04 on dell Inspiron 5537

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kernel, dell, touchpad

After installing Ubuntu23.04 on my dell computer every thing worked fine, the day after i started the laptop and the touchpad was not working at all, i am a totally knew person to linux i just switched from windows so if anyone can help me out here i'd really appreciate it.

NOTE: I am using a mouse now, and i had touchpad issues when i was on windows sometiems it was working and somtimes not.
here are some info that might help.

model: Inspiron 5537
tag model: 7YVMPX1
kernel version: Linux 6.2.0-20-generic
OS type: 64-bit
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-4200U × 4
Firmware version: A08
Gnome version: 44.0
Windowing system: Wayland

```
zen@mrobot:~$ xinput
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for 
details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                   id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15          id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15          id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]


zen@mrobot:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics 
Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] 
(rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express 
Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 
01)
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 
8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
```

Comment: Looks for me like a hardware issue.

Comment: @nobody are you saying that i have to buy a new touchpad for my laptop?,but it was working when i setup the OS(Ubuntu), the problem occured after a day after that

Comment: You wrote you has also sometimes problems in windows with it.  Maybe contact problem.

Comment: @nobody what do you mean by contact problem?

Comment: I mean there your touchpad is connected to the Mainboard

Answer (score 0):

After i got really frustrated i just reinstalled Ubuntu but the 22.04, and the touch pad is working.